# symfony 3.4 service alias

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-3.4

i try this code

```
mea_memento.datatables.correspondence_datatable:
    alias: Mea\MementoBundle\Datatables\CorrespondenceDatatable
    class: Mea\MementoBundle\Datatables\CorrespondenceDatatable
    parent: sg_datatables.datatable.abstract
```

try get CorrespondenceDatatable::class - service not found 
i cannot setup new naming -

```
Mea\MementoBundle\CorrespondenceDatatable:
    parent: sg_datatables.datatable.abstract

Service definition "Mea\MementoBundle\CorrespondenceDatatable" has a parent but no class, and its name looks like a FQCN. Either the class is missing or you want to inherit it from the parent service. To resolve this ambiguity, please rename this service to a non-FQCN (e.g. using dots), or create the missing class.
```